# mysql query to fetch these results

Tags: php, mysql

i have three tables
1.**project_ref_table** with columns
project_id(pk)
project_name
client_id(fk)
project_description

and 2.**client_ref_table** with column
client_id(pk)
client_name
client_email
client_address

3.**emp_ref_table**
emp_id(pk)
emp_name
emp_address
project_id(fk)
dept_id
**Suppose user who login with his emp_id is a manager and i need to fetch his client list with their project like this**

**client_name|client_email|client_address|project_name**

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Do you have a variable containing the logged in id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join 3 tables emp_ref_table, project_ref_table and client_ref_table.

```
select c.client_name, c.client_email, c.address,p.project_name
from emp_ref_table e, project_ref_table p, client_ref_table c
where e.project_id= p.project_id and p.client_id = c.client_id  and e.id = current_user_id
```

current_user_id = current manager user id.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT client_name,client_email,client_address,project_name from
project_ref_table INNER JOIN client_ref_table 
ON(project_ref_table.client_id=client_ref_table.client_id)LEFT JOIN 
emp_ref_table
ON(project_ref_table.project_id=emp_ref_table.project_id)
WHERE emp_ref_table.emp_id='employee id'
```